# Faster scrolling background

Tags: android

I am developing a (vertical) scrolling shooter app for android. Everything is working fine, its fast and smooth... but so far it just has a black background. I wanted to make a scrolling background by creating a very tall bitmap of the background, and show a part of it using code like this:

```
canvas.drawBitmap(background_bitmap, sample_rect, fullscreen_rect, null);
```

where the sample_rect gets moved along as the game progresses. The code works, but the frame rate has now plummeted and is no longer smooth.

I can think of some possible ways to do this better, but it seems silly to reinvent the wheel if there is a standard method that everyone uses. Any suggestions?

**EDIT:** By the way the image is not a simple pattern that I can implement with small tiles.

**EDIT:** Should I be employing BitmapShader? Should I resize my bitmap to match the screen before the game starts?

Comment: Wny you are not using OpenGL?

Comment: Isn't that overkill? My game is just 2D. I thought OpenGL was a massive package, with a huge learning curve, designed for 3D stuff.

Comment: Open GL is not 3D only. It is for exactly this situations. Of course "raw" Open GL is not exactly done quickly, it pays to use (and learn) an abstracting game engine like e.g. http://www.andengine.org/ (which is easy to learn, scrolling backgrounds are a piece of cake).